# How can I securely store private key in iOS?

Tags: ios, security

I'm creating app for iOS in the Xcode. There will be the **private key** that will be **the same** for all users (clients). What is the best way to store it on the client side (in iOS)? in what form should I store it and where is the best place? In which form it is better to put it in the installation package? I will use this key to encrypt the data. Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: You can store it in the keychain, read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Comment: Secrets stored on the client are no longer secret. How are you planning to use this encrypted data? There must be a better alternative.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I've decided not to store private key on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safest and recomended way would be receiving the encrypted private key from a server (via a https connection) and the storing it in the secure container (Keychain).